# Future[Try[Option[Int]]] giving error found : models.TenantGlobalBranding [error] required: scala.concurrent.Future[?]

Tags: scala, playframework, future

I have an **Int:Future[Try[Option[Int]]]** from which I need that Int value. I have a code like this :

```
def fun(number: Future[Try[Option[Int]]]): Future[Result] = {
  val num: Int = number.flatMap(x => processTry(x))
}

def processTry(x: Try[Option[Int]]): Int = processOption(x.getOrElse(Some(101)))
def processOption(x: Option[Int]): Int = x.getOrElse(101)
```

I am getting this error **required: scala.concurrent.Future[?]**

Comment: What is `process`, `process2`? What are their signatures? Please post a [MCVE] of your problem.

Answer (score 1):

You can leverage pattern matching to process the answer and the error cases very cleanly:

```
val result: Future[Try[Option[Int]]]
result.onComplete {
  case Success(Success(Some(i))) => // you get your i: Int
  case Success(Success(None)) => // you get None
  case _ => // Either the `Future` or the `Try` failed, you could also process both cases separately
}
```

Answer (score 0):

1. Your `number.flatMap` requires that lambda return `Future[Int]`. Instead `processTry` is defined as `: Int`. You may replace `flatMap` with `map`.
2. You have defined `num` as `Int`, whereas the result of `fun` is `Future[Result]`. Have you missed some code?
3. `val num = ...` has type `Unit` and it is different from function type.

The code might look like

```
def fun(number: Future[Try[Option[Int]]]): Future[Result] = {
  val num: Future[Int] = number.map(x => processTry(x))
  num.map{i => Result(i)}
}
```